# An attempt to intuitively derive the Gamma distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I study a course in probability theory these days and i have came across the notion of the Gamma distribution, which describes the probability distribution of the sum $Z_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$, where $X_i$ is a random variable which has the exponential distribution $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ ($f_X(x)=\Gamma(1,\lambda)$). The standard derivation of the probability density function for $\Gamma(n,\lambda)$ is by first deriving the cumulutive probability function using a summation of probabilities that are calculated from the theory of Poisson process (each term in the sum is the probability that there are $k$ events ($0\le k\le n $) in the interval $[0,x]$), and than taking a derivative of the cumulutive distribution to get the probability density function.

However, i find this technical derivation not transparent enough, and i tried to think on it in a different way. But i was only partially succesful in my way and i'll be glad if someone will help me complete it.

**Intuitive explanation of the Gamma distribution**

The "intuitive way" is by induction. The event $z_0\le Z_n\le z_0+\epsilon$ is composed of all the sub-events   of the form $(Z_{n-1} = t)\cap (X_n = z_0-t)$, where $t$ is a dummy variable running on the interval $[0,z_0]$. Each such event has a probability $(\frac{\lambda^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t} t^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)}dt)\cdot (\lambda e^{-\lambda (z_0-t)} \, dt)= \frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda z_0} t^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)}(dt)^2$. Therefore, by summing up all those probabilities when $t$ is running on $[0,z_0],$ one gets a constant times $\int_0^{z_0}t^{n-1} \, dt = \frac{t^n}{n},$ and hence the dependency of $\Gamma(n,\lambda)$ on the Gamma function $\Gamma(n)$ and the $n$-th power of $z_0$.

My problem is not in the induction step but rather in the basis of induction (moving from $n=1$ to $n=2$). I can't understand why $\Gamma(2,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^2e^{-\lambda x} x}{2}$ rather than $\Gamma(2,\lambda)=\lambda^2e^{-\lambda x} x$?

Comment: Required: $\int_0^\infty \Gamma(2,\lambda)dx=1$.

Comment: In fact:  $\Gamma(x\mid 2,\lambda)=\lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}x\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}$.  It *should* **not** be divided by $2$.

Comment: It's easiest with [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)). Are you can familiar with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental rule of integration:

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^x\int_0^{x-t} g(s,t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s &=\int_0^x g(x-t, t)\,\mathrm d t\end{align}$$

Now the sum of one exponential distributed random variable is of course exponentially distributed.

$$\begin{aligned}\Gamma(x\mid 1,\lambda)&=\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{\lambda^1\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,x^0}{\Gamma(1)}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\end{aligned}$$

So, the pdf for the sum of two iid exponential random variables is:

$$\begin{align}\Gamma(x\mid 2,\lambda) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^x\int_0^{x-t} \Gamma(s\mid 1,\lambda)\cdot\Gamma(t\mid 1,\lambda)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^x\int_0^{x-t} \lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda (s+t)}\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex] &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \int_0^x \lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda (x-t+t)}\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex]&=\lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \int_0^x\mathrm d t\\[1ex] &= \lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,x\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\\[2ex] &=\dfrac{\lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,x^{2-1}}{\Gamma(2)}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x} \end{align}$$

---

Likewise, if indeed $\Gamma(x\mid n,\lambda)=\dfrac{\lambda^{n}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,x^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}$

$$\begin{align}\Gamma(x\mid n+1,\lambda) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^x\int_0^{x-t} \Gamma(t\mid n,\lambda)\cdot \Gamma(s\mid 1,\lambda)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex] &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \int_0^x \dfrac{\lambda^{n+1}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,t^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\lambda^{n+1}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(n)}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\, \int_0^x t^{n-1}\mathrm d t\\[1ex] &= \dfrac{\lambda^{n+1}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}x^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x} \end{align}$$

---

Therefore, for all $n\geq 1$, $\Gamma(x\mid n,\lambda)=\dfrac{\lambda^n\,\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\,x^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}$